# $\lim\limits_{m, l\to\infty} \frac{m+a}{m+a+l+b}$ where $m + l = N$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, machine-learning, bayesian

I have been working on Bishop's book, Machine Learning and Pattern Recognition. The page 73 says, the limit of an infinitely large data set $m, l \rightarrow \infty$, the result $\frac{m+a}{m+a+l+b}$ reduces to $\frac{m}{N}$. Where $m$ is number of $x = 1$ observations and $l$ is number of $x = 0$ observations. Hence, $N = m + l$ is the size of the data set.

But I did not get the limit part, how was the limit's result become $\frac{m}{N}$?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: What steps have you taken so far? Are $a,b$ constants in this quotient, and what might that imply about their relevance in the limit?

Comment: Actually, none. If I had not seen the actual result, I would have said that result is zero.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are just constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing by $m$, we get
$$\lim_{m, l\to\infty} \frac{m+a}{m+l+a+b}=\lim_{m, l\to\infty} \frac{1+a/m}{(m+l)/m+a/m+b/m}=\lim_{m, l\to\infty}\frac{m}{m+l}=\lim_{m, l\to\infty}\frac{m}{N}$$
But I don't think the result is just $m/N$ as you mention.

Comment: Oh, I see. I understand what Bishop meant. Thanks for the answer.